# When more updates?

Tags: updates

Anybody know when there will be new updates, Loki style, Freya, Luna, or 1.0.

I can not find any type of information, I am new and I do not know how often there is a big update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next release will be 0.5 (Juno), and it will be based on Ubuntu 18.04. The earliest possible release date would be sometime in April of 2018, but It might be a couple of months later until it actually gets released. Hope this helped!